# What is the force that enables Mjolnir to return to the hand of Thor

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, mjolnir

What powers Mjolnir to return to the hand of Thor? 
These two questions do not answer this, but do provide some insight,

- [Was Thor unworthy during “The Avengers”?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16346/was-thor-unworthy-during-the-avengers)
- [Why doesn't Thor's hammer return to his hand on Earth? (Avengers - The movie) [duplicate]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16763/why-doesnt-thors-hammer-return-to-his-hand-on-earth-avengers-the-movie)

Wiki states,

> The hammer has two properties relating to movement. When it is
>   deliberately thrown by Thor, it will return to his hand despite any
>   intervening obstacles or distance, even traveling through planets to
>   return to Thor. When it has been dropped or set aside, it takes a
>   fixed position, from which it cannot be moved except by a 'worthy'
>   individual.

Even though it states why it returns, it does not state what force is working to return it to Thor. Is there somewhere else that states how it comes back to Thor?

Comment: Asgardian magic?

Comment: It's not magic, just science that's indistinguishable from magic.

Comment: It is achieved by entering the following command into the Matrix: `System.summonMjolnir(this);` which is the system function to transport Mjolnir to the caller (aka `this`). Note that the function will only execute if the truth value returned by `System.checkIsWorthy(this);` is `true`.

Comment: Force of personality.

Comment: @thegreatjedi, you sure it is not, `Worthy.summon.mjolnir(thor).ToHand();`

Comment: Just as the Flash has the Speed Force in the DC universe, Mjolnir has the Return Force.

Comment: @KyloRen Nope. `Worthy` is not an object. More accurately, `if (Mjolnir.heldBy(whosoever)) { if (Person.isWorthy(whosoever)) { Person.gainsPower(whosoever, Asgardians.Thor); }}`

Comment: @Valorum, to that I say: http://abstrusegoose.com/120

Answer (score 2):

I have to say that it is magic. I agree with Valorum when he/she says that magic is just indistinguishable from science. However since we can't really explain the science behind this I'm going to just call it magic.

Mjolnir has several enchantments but the one we're looking for here is this one: it returns to the exact spot from which it is thrown and returns to Thor when summoned.

So it is magic or just *very* advanced science, whichever way you decide to look at it.

Sources:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mjolnir_(comics)